# What's the meaning of -m when doing git commit

Tags: git

When I do a git commit, I would include a note proceeded by -m. I'm always wondering what exactly does -m mean. I know there are other similar type of notations used when doing command line stuff, such as -a, -b, and etc. What exactly does the slash line mean?

Comment: maybe means message?

Comment: Reading the documentation is a great way to answer your questions.

Comment: The option derives from the Japanese word `申し送り`, pronounced _moushiokuri_ which can be roughly translated as _message_ to English. In the original git implementation, the option was supposed to be written as `-申`, but due to problems in non-unicode-environments, this was later replaced by `-m`. So if you see it, always think of _moushiokuri_.

Answer (score 0):

The `-m` is a short option.  Traditionally, options on Unix are introduced with a single dash for short options, or a double dash for long options.  There can be both for the same argument, and in this case the corresponding long option for `-m` is `--message`.

That's because this option introduces a commit message.  If you don't specify one on the command line, then Git will open an editor to prompt you to write one.  Typically, since we want to write detailed commit messages explaining why we've made a change, it's less common to use the `-m` or `--message` options.

You can see the documentation for `git commit` by running `git commit --help`.  On a Unix system, that will typically invoke `man`, which is the manual page reader, to show you the documentation for the command.  On Windows, typically it opens an HTML page.  If you're using `man`, you can also invoke it for commands itself, such as `man man` (to see the documentation for `man` itself) or `man sh` to see the documentation for the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Read document, before asking is the best way to learn.

[git commit document](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

```
-m <msg>
--message=<msg>
Use the given <msg> as the commit message. If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.
```